# How can I use BibTeX to cite a case study?

Tags: bibtex, citing

For example, I have [this](https://www.housingauthority.gov.hk/mini-site/hasr1314/en/common/pdf/09.pdf) case study. I want to cite it in BibTeX, how can I do that? I am using the bibliography style: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` which call-out citations numerically. I am NOT using any citation management package such as `cite`, `natbib`, `apacite`, etc.

Other details of the example case study are as follow:

Hong Kong Housing Authority Sustainability Report 2013/14; Noise Mitigation through Innovative Designs and Measures Case Study 2. (Dated 2015-01-28)

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? Is your citation call-out style numeric or author-year? Do you use a citation management package such as `cite`, `natbib`, or `apacite`?

Comment: I am using the bibliography style: \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} which call-out citations numerically. I am not using any citation management package. I have edited the question.

Comment: You should be able to use the form I gave in my answer. For sure, it’s compatible with the IEEEtrran bib style. Just make sure you load the `url` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't exactly provided much information about your bibliography setup. Hence, the following answer is necessarily rather minimalist as it doesn't make any far-reaching assumptions (which may or may not apply in your document).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{hkha:2014,
  author = "{Hong Kong Housing Authority}",
  title  = "{Sustainability Report 2013/14; Case} Study~2: {Noise} 
            Mitigation through Innovative Designs and Measures",
  year   = 2014,
  note   = "\url{https://www.housingauthority.gov.hk/mini-site/hasr1314/en/common/pdf/09.pdf}, last checked on 2018-01-23",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % change 'numbers' to 'authoryear,round' if needed
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bibliography style
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{hkha:2014}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```