# How to cite a CAD file?

Tags: bibtex, latex-misc

I want to insert a CAD file as an entry in my `.bib` file using `@misc`.
But it gives some errors.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
```

my entry:

```
@misc{period2,
  author = {period},
  title = {err_or.gds},
  howpublished = {email},
  year = {2018},
  date = {07 August 2018},
  note = {Format:gds}
}
```

I looked many examples like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411672/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-case-study), which uses `\RequirePackage{filecontents}`.
But it seems that the entry must be in the `.tex` file.
When I put the entry in `.bib` file, `\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}` is not read.
I prefer to put the entry in `.bib` file together with other normal papers, books, etc.

Comment: I don't quite get what exactly the error is. Can you describe it a bit more, maybe including a small but complete example? And: Why do you use `filecontents`? As it seems to me, you could create the `.bib` file without problems manually. And also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me.

I do not use `filecontents` currently. I mentioned it before just to show what I already googled, that many suggestions use `filecontents` for miscellaneous entries. 

What I have now is only that entry `@misc` in .bib and that error I mentioned above. I  do not know what the problem is.

Comment: If I delete that `@misc`, the error is gone.

I do not think I need a special package to use `@misc` or do I?
Is there any wrong format in the entry?

Comment: Can you add your tex file as well? (In a minified version, meaning all things that are not required are removed). - The `filecontents` is only used to have it all in one place, you can completely forget about it. - without @misc the whole entry gets ignored (which we don't want)

Comment: it seems the problem is I used underscore `_` in the title field. I edit the post above. thanks.

Comment: Have you solved your own problem? If it is solved, you should write an answer - not edit your question. I am not sure if it is of usage to others or not (question should be closed) !?

Comment: If the entry is meant for `biblatex`, the `date` field has the wrong format, it should be `YYYY-MM-DD`, i.e. `date = {2018-08-07},` instead of `date = {07 August 2018},`

Comment: @moewe, yes you are right. such style produce a warning only, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the problem is I used underscore `_` in the `title`field.

solution: There must be no underscore `_` in `title` field.

`title = {err_or.gds},` --> ERROR

`title = {err-or.gds},` --> Correct

`title = {error.gds},` --> Correct